# I need to add all the characters in a entered isbn how would i do that? (python)

Tags: python, addition

```
start = " "
multiplynum = 11
protectedisbn = " "
while start.lower() != "n":
print("Welcome to the isbn number protector!")
start = input ("Would you like to protect your isbn number? (y/n) ")
if start == "y":
    isbn  = input("Please input your 10 digit isbn number. ")
    if len (isbn) != 10:
        print("I am sorry but you need to enter a 10 digit isbn.")
    for ch in isbn:
```

this is where I am stuck I need help in order to get them all to add together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ans = sum([int(i) for i in isbn if i.isdigit()])
print ans
```

Should work for you

The above is the same as saying

```
ans = 0
for i in isbn:
    if i.isdigit():
        ans += int(i)
print ans
```

Comment: so what would I type in order to print that then?

Comment: Assign it to ans, print it

Comment: and I would assign it how? (sorry I am a tad nooby not alot but I don't see how I would assign that bit of code)

Comment: @Xxbat99xX do the print OUTSIDE the loop

Comment: @JakobBowyer Generator expression is better than list comprehension in this case.

Comment: @thefourtheye I didn't want to over confuse him

Comment: @JakobBowyer Atleast he would get to know that there is such a thing in Python, now :)